# Camera pose calibration: couldn't find file camera_pose_calibration_cache.bag

Tags: ros, camera-pose-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

as I followed the camera pose calibration tutorial, I had to include the following lines to my launch files that start up the cameras:

`<include file="$(find camera_pose_calibration)/blocks/calibration_tf_publisher.launch"> <arg name="cache_file" value="/tmp/camera_pose_calibration_cache.bag" /> </include>`

When I start the altered launch-files, I get the following message:
Couldn't find file [/tmp/camera_pose_calibration_cache.bag]. Skipping publishing.

I am able to see the aggregated view of my two cameras and the checkerboard is recognized.
However,  when the bar below each image becomes green, there is no 'beep' sound, indicating that a calibration sample was captured.

I suppose the problem is the lack of my camera nodes finding the camera_pose_calibration_cache.bag.
Is there anyone who has a solution?

Thanks in advance,

Sébastien

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10849/camera-pose-calibration:-couldn%27t-find-file-camera_pose_calibration_cache.bag/) by [Sébastien Ducatteeuw](https://answers.ros.org/users/910/s%C3%A9bastien-ducatteeuw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-08-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The bag file is used to store the results of a previous calibration, so you still see your calibrated cameras in tf after you restart your launch files. This means that the first time you run the calibration, it is normal that the bag won't be there; this is not a problem.

To debug your problem, make sure you have rxconsole open when you're running the calibration, and see what kind of feedback you get. For further questions about the camera_pose_calibration, please start a new topic.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CHz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4559/chz/) on 2013-04-09**:
Hello, I am having same problem. The thing is that beside I don't hear any voice, the program does not save any file when I close it with CTRL+C. And I don't see any tf output on rxconsole. I have also checked for write permissions to the folders and they are ok. Could you please help me about this?

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-06**:
@CHz have you gotten this package to work successfully?  I'm stuck on similar problems.

**Comment by [CHz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4559/chz/) on 2014-01-06**:
Yes, create a file named camera_pose_calibration_cache.bag and put the dir location in launch file. It'll fill it up for you ;)

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-06**:
Thanks! I'm also getting a bunch of other weird errors, I was wondering if anyone had dealt with them or had it running successfully on Hydro: http://answers.ros.org/question/115111/errors-in-camera_pose_calibration-launch-for-3-kinects/

Have any ideas?  I'm new to ROS (started last semester).